# Using Express 4 standalone middleware with Express 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am not quite ready to upgrade my Express 3 installation to Express 4, however I would like to take advantage of some of the upgraded components in Express 4, namely express-session and compression.

I have already tried this, and it seems to be working fine.  However I want to be sure I am not missing anything.  So my question is:  Are there any known problems with using the express-session standalone middleware with Express 3, instead of Express 4 as is intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express 3x actually ships with a [compression](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#compress) library.  If there is a feature you wanted in a version of [the compression module](https://github.com/expressjs/compression/) that is past the one already included, you can just install it according to the documents.  The same goes with `express-session`.

The middleware system hasn't changed from 3x to 4x, only which middleware is included by default.  Check out the [Migration Guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html) for more details.

In short, you should continue to see everything working as expected!

Hope this helps.